# C++ christmas tree

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++ and decided to give myself a challenge by creating a simple Christmas Tree program. Everything has been working so far although the code doesn't produce what I expect. I've spent a decent amount of time trying to figure out what's wrong but can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.

So far, the code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
 char cTree;
 int iSize, iSpace;

 std::cout << "Christmas Tree Application" << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Enter the size of your christmas tree: ";
 std::cin >> iSize;
 std::cout << "Enter the character you would like to use for your tree: ";
 std::cin >> cTree;

 iSpace = iSize / 2;

 for(int i = 0; i < iSize; i++){
    std::string sTree(i, cTree);
    //std::string sSpace(iSpace, ' ');
    std::cout << sTree << std::endl;
    //iSpace -= 1;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I've also commented out the 'spacing' part because whenever I execute it, it creates an error that I have no clue why it is says that. I know I can do the spacings in a different manner but I'd like to use the std::string way. Any help?

Comment: Maybe you should include the errors you are getting.

Comment: Please show expected input/output. I have at least 2 ideas of what your christmas tree should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iSpace` is set to `iSize / 2`, yet you run the loop `iSize` times, decreasing `iSpace` by one every time. Eventually, `iSpace` will be negative, which is why you have the error. Try this:

```
iSpace = iSize;

for(int i = 0; i < iSize; i++){
   std::string sTree(i, cTree);
   std::string sSpace(iSpace, ' ');
   std::cout << sSpace << sTree << sTree << std::endl;
   iSpace -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks this helped me :D also id like to ask if theres anything I should fix with my code to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping on the wrong value for `iSpace`, as it remains constant throughout execution rather than changing like a variable does.

Also, your code can be tidied up a bit. I've posted the updated code below. I've deliberately replaced spaces with underscore characters to provide a better graphical representation of my logic.

Good luck!

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   char cTree;
   int iSize;
   int iSpace;
   int iChars;

   cout << "Christmas Tree Application" << endl;
   cout << "Enter the height of your christmas tree: ";
   cin >> iSize;
   cout << "Enter the character you would like to use for your tree: ";
   cin >> cTree;

   for(int i = 0; i < iSize; i++){
      iSpace = (iSize-i)-1;
      iChars = (2*i)+1;
      string sSpace(iSpace, '_');
      string sTree(iChars, cTree);
      cout << sSpace << sTree << sSpace << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run**

---

```
Christmas Tree Application
Enter the height of your christmas tree: 10
Enter the character you would like to use for your tree: #
_________#_________
________###________
_______#####_______
______#######______
_____#########_____
____###########____
___#############___
__###############__
_#################_
###################
```

Answer (score 0):

awesomeyi is right about the error, however if you'd like it to look more "tree-like" you'll need to double your loop.

i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    char cTree;
    int iSize, iSpace;

    std::cout << "Christmas Tree Application" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of your christmas tree: ";
    std::cin >> iSize;
    std::cout << "Enter the character you would like to use for your tree: ";
    std::cin >> cTree;

    iSpace = iSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < iSize*2; i+=2){
        std::string sTree(i, cTree);
        std::string sSpace(iSpace, ' ');
        std::cout << sSpace + sTree + sSpace<< std::endl;
        iSpace -= 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a recursive implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

void drawTree(int level, int height, char c) {
        if(level > 0)
                drawTree(level-1, height, c);
        std::cout << std::string(height-level, ' ') << std::string((2*level)+1, c) << std::endl;
}

int main(){
        char cTree;
        int iSize;
        std::cout << "Christmas Tree Application" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter the size of your christmas tree: ";
        std::cin >> iSize;
        std::cout << "Enter the character you would like to use for your tree: ";
        std::cin >> cTree;
        drawTree(iSize, iSize, cTree);
        return 0;
}
```